# TSQL Trim - Portable Method

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string in the following format 'DOMAIN\username'.

I wish to trim the domain and the backslash from the string. I cannont simply use RIGHT() as we have multiple domains of varying length.

What is the most portable way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: "Portable Method" -- portable to past/future versions of SQL Server, other SQL products, or something else?

Comment: If there are multiple domains, it sounds kind of dangerous to be stripping domain information away from the usernames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select Right('DOMAIN\UserName', Len('DOMAIN\UserName') - Charindex('\', 'DOMAIN\UserName'))`

Comment: @LukeH - so it does. Couldn't see that for looking.  I've amended my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: Still broken! It coinicidentally works for this specific example, but what about `ANOTHERDOMAIN\username` or `DOMAIN\anotherusername`?

Comment: @LukeH - Wow,  my brain is just not switched on today.  Sorted it now.

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
select substring('DOMAIN\username',  charindex('\' ,'DOMAIN\username')+1, len('DOMAIN\username'))
```